# Only the homepage redirects to www, the internal pages throw an error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have an issue with this Wordpress website:
http://www.pitahouse.com/

I want all the pages to redirect to the www version. Unfortunately, I can't accomplish this. Right now, only the homepage redirects to its www version (if I type pitahouse.com in the browser it will redirect to www). Whenever I try to type the path to an internal page in the browser without www (pitahouse.com/catering/), it throws either 404 or 403 error instead of redirecting to the www version.

I've tried all the solutions I could find, like adding these code snippets and similar to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

But none of those have worked.

Do you have any idea what might be causing this issue and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I assume you replaced example.com with pitahouse.com before copying these lines to .htaccess? And also are aware, what kind of web server you are running?

Comment: Yes, it was replaced with pitahouse.com. It's Apache server

Comment: Yes, the one that serves `www.pitahouse.com` is Apache. But the one that serves `pitahouse.com`?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by that. Could you explain it please?

Comment: http://browserspy.dk/webserver.php - shows Apache, for both versions.

Comment: Yes, the first result in Google. But they are lying. The next one is more accurate: https://www.ultratools.com/tools/websiteServerResult?domainName=pitahouse.com

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the domains `pitahouse.com` and `www.pitahouse.com` are somehow hosted in different servers. When you ping for them, you get different IPs. See below:
[image: Ping results for pitahouse.com and www.pitahouse.com]

Comment: Oh my God... thanks for the info. How this might have happened? What are my options here?

Comment: NVM I got it. The DNS were not configured properly. Thank you very much! The issues is solved.

Comment: Where are you hosting the domains? talk with your hosts. They might be able to resolve this for you.